# Developing a Python toolbox for multi decision criteria analysis

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, sql, python-toolbox

I am trying to get my hands dirty with Python toolboxes (.pyt) for ArcGIS Pro.

I've learned a lot about how to configure the parameters for the ArcGIS Pro GUI, but my lack of SQL knowledge is really blocking further progress in the execute portions of the toolbox.

A specific problem I have is with how the `arcpy.da.SearchCursor()` function works. I'm trying to work with it as though it's a Python for loop, but I'm having a lot of trouble.

An example:

```
class WeightedSumScore(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the tool (tool name is the name of the class)."""
        self.label = "Weighted Sum Score"
        self.description = "Takes standardized data from a site attribute table and user-provided weights, performs a weighted-sum operation, and returns a score and a numerical ranking for each site."
        self.canRunInBackground = False

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        """Define parameter definitions"""
        input_table = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Input Table",
            name="input_table",
            datatype="GPTableView",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")

        fields = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Fields",
            name="fields",
            datatype="Field",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input",
            multiValue=True,
            enabled=False)
        fields.parameterDependencies = [input_table.name]

        weights = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Weights",
            name="weights",
            datatype="Double",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input",
            multiValue=True)

        score_field_name = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Score Field Name",
            name="score_field_name",
            datatype="GPString",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")

        rank_field_name = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Rank Field Name",
            name="rank_field_name",
            datatype="GPString",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")
        
        parameters = [input_table, fields, weights, score_field_name, rank_field_name]
        return parameters

    def updateParameters(self, parameters):
        """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
        validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
        has been changed."""
        if parameters[0].altered:
            parameters[1].enabled = True

    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        """The source code of the tool."""
        input_table = parameters[0].valueAsText
        fields = parameters[1].valueAsText
        weights = parameters[2].values

        # Create a list to store the weighted sum score for each site
        weighted_sum_scores = []
        arcpy.AddMessage(f"Fields = {fields}")

        # Calculate the weighted sum score for each site
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(input_table, fields) as cursor: #<--error
            for row in cursor:
                weighted_sum_score = 0
                for i, value in enumerate(row):
                    weighted_sum_score += value * weights[i]
                    weighted_sum_scores.append(weighted_sum_score)

        # Sort the weighted sum scores and create a list of rankings
        rankings = [i+1 for i in sorted(range(len(weighted_sum_scores)), key=lambda x: weighted_sum_scores[x], reverse=True)]

        # Return the weighted sum scores and rankings
        return weighted_sum_scores, rankings
```

The above code returns the following error:

```
RuntimeError: An invalid SQL statement was used. [Select OBJECTID, {my vars} FROM {my data layer}.
```

Comment: You don't need a full toolbox to generate a minimal code sample. Please cut this down to the part of the code that's actually being executed.

Comment: Try either `fields = parameters[1].values` or `fields = [f for f in parameters[1].valueAsText.split(";")]`